# Fully understanding Ruby class variable

Tags: ruby

In this code block,

```
@@y = 1
class MyClass
 @@y = 2
end
p @@y # => 2
```

naively, it seems that `@@y` is in top-level scope, and it isn't the same `@@y` as the one in `MyClass`'s scope. Why is `@@y` affected by the class `MyClass` definition? (why is the result `2`?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at this example. Here `@@x` in `Bar` is indeed separate from `@@x` in `Foo`.

```
class Foo
  @@x = 1
end

class Bar
  @@x = 2
end

Foo.class_variable_get(:@@x) # => 1
Bar.class_variable_get(:@@x) # => 2
```

But what happens if `Bar` is a child of `Foo`?

```
class Foo
  @@x = 1
end

class Bar < Foo
  @@x = 2
end

Foo.class_variable_get(:@@x) # => 2
Bar.class_variable_get(:@@x) # => 2
```

In this case, `@@x` is the same in both cases, and it is the one declared in `Foo`.

Now, back to your example:

```
@@y = 1
class MyClass
  @@y = 2
end
p @@y
```

The first line declares class variable in the root scope. Root is a special object `main` which is of type `Object`. So, essentially, you're defining a class variable on `Object` class. Since everything is an `Object`, this is how definition of `MyClass` also inherits `@@y` and is able to change it.

Comment: Sergio, thanks very much! That is a fine answer. Here is a corollary question: `@@y = 1` `class MyClass` `end` `p MyClass.class_variable_get(:@@y)` `p MyClass.class_variables` Why doesn't #class_variables show @@y?

Comment: @sploiber: Because it shows only class variables that this class owns. See the documentation: [Module.class_variables](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-class_variables)

Comment: If `Bar` is able to change the value of `@@y` in its superclass `Object`, why doesn't `Bar` change the value of `@@y` in its superclass `Foo`?

Comment: @SébastienLeCallonnec: it does, look closer :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Darn, you're right, time to clean my glasses.  (=

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
@@y = 1
```

you are defining it on Object. Since MyClass is a subclass of Object, it has access to it's class variables.

```
@@y = 1
class MyClass
  @@y = 2
end
p @@y
puts MyClass.superclass #=> Object
puts Object.class_variables #=> @@y
```

Comment: I like both, actually; yours is more complete and adds a fuller picture. But all of this helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Global vars are like this:

```
$y = 1
```

and class vars are like this:

```
@@y = 1
```

So actually your using the class vars

here is a link: [vars](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Global_Variables)

Comment: There's no word "global" in the question :)

Comment: OP asked *why* the class vars were behaving as observed, so must have known they were class vars. The problem was not understand the nature of Ruby class var inheritance.

Comment: Dave, yes, that is right. This exchange helped me with a fuller understanding of class variables.